# remove double quotation curvy from string “” bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am having really a time removing double quotation "curvy" from a text file.

I've tried already using awk, sed, etc...

It seems that the character it is simply not recognize.

Example input:

```
“The bear did not try hard enough”
```

Expected output:

```
The bear did not try hard enough
```

Comment: Probably nothing. I especially like the "etc" part :)

Comment: Strange, `etc input.txt` usually works for me.

Comment: Already tried  `sed 's/^”//' ` or `sed 's/\“//g'`,  every time I try something with tr, i have the same error message as below...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
“The bear did not try hard enough”

$ tr -d '[“”]' < file
The bear did not try hard enough
```

Make sure you copy/paste the quotes from your input file into the `tr` command instead of trying to re-type them manually as the double quotes on your keyboard are not the same character(s) as apparently appear in your input file.

In my experience the bear DID try hard enough, he just couldn't quite escape with the pic-a-nic baskets....

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i get this error :

iconv: (stdin):427:5: cannot convert

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like you're executing some tool named `iconv` and it's got some kind of error. Maybe you should post a question about that?

Comment: Thanks again, indeed the problem came from codage ISO-8859-1 to utf-8